# Group anagrams big O doesn't seem to hold up, is there a mistake?

Tags: python, hashmap, time-complexity

The goal is to group words in the same list if they are anagrams. Words can only contain `a` `b` `c` or `d`.

Input:

`["abc","acb","add","dda","ddd","aaa"]`

Should give output:

`[['abc', 'acb'], ['add', 'dda'], ['ddd'], ['aaa']]`

`n` will denote the number of strings in my input.

`m` will denote the length of each string in my input.

The first solution is the more natural one and is `O(n * mlogm) time`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def groupAnagrams(strs: list[str]) -> list[list[str]]:  # O(n * mlogm) time
    mapping = defaultdict(list)
    for s in strs:  # O(n)
        sig = "".join(sorted(s))  # O(m*logm)
        mapping[sig].append(s)
    return list(mapping.values())

print(groupAnagrams(["abc","acb","add","dda","ddd","aaa"]))
```

The second solution uses a trick making it `# O(n * m) time`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def groupAnagrams2(strs: list[str]) -> list[list[str]]:  # O(n * m) time
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for s in strs:  # O(n)
        count = [0]*4
        for c in s:  # O(m)
            count[ord(c) - ord("a")] += 1
        res[tuple(count)].append(s)  # O(4)
    return list(res.values())

print(groupAnagrams(["abc","acb","add","dda","ddd","aaa"]))
```

Both solutions seem to be working.

On small lists and on big lists, solution 1 is faster even though, asymptotically, solution 2 should be faster. Does someone know why?

Small lists:

```py
groupAnagrams(["abc","acb","add","dda","ddd","aaa"]) -> 2.21 µs ± 23.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
groupAnagrams2(["abc","acb","add","dda","ddd","aaa"]) -> 3.02 µs ± 18.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Big lists:

```py
import random
random_strings = ["".join([chr(random.randint(97, 100)) for _ in range(100000)]) for _ in range(1000)]
groupAnagrams(random_strings) -> 5.48 s ± 33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
groupAnagrams2(random_strings) -> 7.13 s ± 83.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Since the thing being sorted is an array of characters from a finite (small) alphabet (some might say "string") it's possible to sort it in linear time and some sorting algorithms do that naturally without special-casing it (eg 3-way quicksort). IDK if Python does that.

Comment: It's often hard to catch `O(n)` vs `O(n*logn)` difference in practice, especially in interpreted, very high-level languages like python. You most probably hit some internal optimization - if one of theoretically faster does more python operations, while theoretically slower has more C implementation, the latter will execute faster. Also 100_000 may be not big enough, maybe you're not approaching asymptotic complexity yet.

Comment: Furthermore, seemingly inefficient `sig = frozenset(Counter(s).items())` (it's `O(m)`, if I'm not too dead near 5am) does twice better than your `sorted` solution om my PC. This almost fully confirms that you're just hitting C vs Python optimization layers somewhere, and debugging that would take more time than I can afford (profile on C level and see, if you feel strongly interested).

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike If you want fast, map s.count over "abcd".

Answer (score 1):

The sorting might not be linear but linearithmic but we can barely see the difference with a linear tendency, which explains why we don't see an advantage:

Running this code:

```py
import time
import random

random_strings = ["".join([chr(random.randint(97, 100)) for _ in range(i+500)]) for i in range(0, 2_000_000, 10)]

list_times = []
for random_string in random_strings:
    start_time = time.time()
    sorted_string = "".join(sorted(random_string))
    list_times.append(time.time() - start_time)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(list(range(500, 2_000_500, 10)), list_times)
plt.ylabel("Time (s)")
plt.xlabel("Length of string to sort (chars)")
plt.show()
```

Yields this:
[image]

Be careful, might be long to run, play with the step to decrease the time it takes to run.

Up to 2*10e7:
[image]

Comment: It isn't linear. The linearithmic part of the runtime just has a very small hidden constant.

Comment: Well `Counting Sort` is linear right?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what Python does.

Comment: So the conclusion is rather that seeing the difference between O(n) and O(nlogn) is very hard unless n is huge?

Comment: Yes, in theory, with huge enough n you should eventually be able to see it, but I'm not sure a computer with enough memory exists. You can btw speed up the testing using `random.choices` (or build a max-len random string once and then test slices of it).

Comment: Btw what monster computer do you have? I can't imagine that code running in less than a minute.

Comment: It's a Lenovo Legion, but I didn't time it exactly, it was probably more like 5-10 minutes?

Comment: Currently running up to 2*10e7 to see if I can see a difference but I don't think I ever will

Comment: Actually it must have taken **a lot** longer. Your plot shows the average was over 0.06 seconds per test, and your code does 200,000 tests. That's 0.06\*200,000 = 12,000 seconds = 200 minutes.

Comment: Yep possible, that's why I edited my post to remove anything and added advice for those who'd want to run it too. I relaunched it and it took more than five minutes so I stopped it.

Comment: But this shows https://imgur.com/8tChczx how tough it'd be to see a difference with linear anyway so no point in running anything

Comment: I'm trying to see if we can see a difference between `sorted` in python which uses timsort (O(nlogn)) and a count sort for an array that only contain zeros, ones and twos (O(3n)). But it's gonna take more than a day to see anything I think. I'll show the results here but I'm afraid `sorted` is coded in `c` and my counted sort in `python` which will result in worse performance for counted sort anyway.